# How to mute enter-perssed sound in TextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, textbox

I have this simple code:

```
private void Term_TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
        Definition_TextBox.Focus();
```

that focuses next TextBox in my form after enter was pressed. Unfortunetly there is this windows-like "bung"/"bing" sound while pressing entere in a TextBox. How to disable it?
I tried to google it but couldn't find any suitable answer. I don't want to mute whole application, only this element, this exact TextBox. Do you know how to do it? Is there any 'elegent' solution to this problem? I'm using .NET Framework 4.7.2 with c#.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 private void Term_TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
  if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
    e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    Definition_TextBox.Focus();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.suppresskeypress?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Comment: Nice to hear. Would you please mark my answer then? Thanks in advice